# How to create a proper mySQL CREATE TABLE statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying insert this query using PHP into the mySQL database but I keep getting this error:

> Can't create table `ecommerce1`.`orders` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

How would I form this statement correctly?

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `date_created` (`date_created` ASC),
INDEX `transaction_id` (`transaction_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

echo "<p>************</p>";
echo $query;
echo "<p>************</p>";

if($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "<p>Database table orders created</p>";
}
else {
echo "<p>Error: </p>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: You are specifying a foreign key constraint, in order for that to work that field in that table must exist and they have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

That can't be the case. If you are getting this error that meant somehow both the key column doesn't match by definition (most probably datatype mismatch). If I try with below example code it works fine. See this fiddle for demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a15c

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `date_created` (`date_created` ASC),
INDEX `transaction_id` (`transaction_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`payment_amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `date_created` (`date_created` ASC),
INDEX `transaction_id` (`transaction_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT char SET utf8;
```